# Chaincode container can't connect to the local peer due to certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, root-certificate

First of all I'd like to mention, that my setup works like a charm when there's no TLS enabled. It works even in Docker Swarm on AWS.

The problem starts when I enable TLS. When I deploy my .bna file via Composer, my newly created chaincode container produces the following logs:

```
2017-08-23 13:14:16.389 UTC [Composer] Info -> INFO 001 Setting the Composer pool size to 8
2017-08-23 13:14:16.402 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 002 Error trying to connect to local peer: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error starting chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Funny thing is, that this works when deploying .bna via the composer playground (when the TLS is still enabled in my fabric)...

Below is my connection profile:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "type": "hlfv1",
    "orderers": [
        {
            "url": "grpcs://orderer.company.com:7050",
            "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----blabla1\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        }
    ],
    "channel": "channelname",
    "mspID": "CompanyMSP",
    "ca": {
        "url": "https://ca.company.com:7054",
        "name": "ca-company",
        "trustedRoots": [
            "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nblabla2\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        ],
        "verify": true
    },
    "peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpcs://peer0.company.com:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpcs://peer0.company.com:7053",
            "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nbalbla3\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        }
    ],
    "keyValStore": "/home/composer/.composer-credentials",
    "timeout": 300
}
```

My certs have been generated by `cryptogen` tool, hence:

- orderers.0.cert contains value of `crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/company.com/orderers/orderer.company.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.company.com-cert.pem`
- peers.0.cert contains value of `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/company.com/peers/peer0.company.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.company.com-cert.pem`
- ca.trustedRoots.0 contains `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/company.com/peers/peer0.company.com/tls/ca.crt`

I've got the feeling, that my trustedRoots certificate is wrong...

**UPDATE**
When I do `docker inspect chaincode_container` I can see that it misses ENV variable: `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt`, while the chaincode container deployed via playground does have it...

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @jmcnevin no I didn't. I gave up after a day or two :/

Answer (score 0):

When the chaincode image is built, the TLS certificate that it uses to build the trusted roots is the [rootcert](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L216) from:

```
# TLS Settings

# Note that peer-chaincode connections through chaincodeListenAddress is
# not mutual TLS auth. See comments on chaincodeListenAddress for more info
tls:
    enabled:  false
    cert:
        file: tls/server.crt
    key:
        file: tls/server.key
    rootcert:
        file: tls/ca.crt
```

The TLS certificate that the peer uses to run the gRPC service is the [cert](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L211) one.

By the way - You're using the release branch code, not the one in master - is that correct?

Comment: I use docker version 1.0.0 for fabric. Based on your answer my root cert was valid for the ca. But when I changed the cert for peer to the one you told me to change to, it doesn't work now at all and I get this: `1 ssl_transport_security.c:947] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0825 09:19:59.277837864       1 ssl_transport_security.c:947] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.`

Comment: Also, I'm talking about hyperledger composer connection. Not the fabric itself. My fabric peer has a valid configuration for those: ` 
    CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
    CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
    CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt`